# Vaadin 6.x how to close external window when application is closed

Tags: window, vaadin

I have a problem to find out how to close an external window when the user session expires, and I have urls with pattern "/ui/*" is protected in web.xml configurations and I'm using JBoss 7.1.1

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

IMO, no quick and easy solution. Server knows when session expired, but client doesn't - it will know only when next request to server is sent. You have to implement some mechanism to notify the client, server push is one of them. Btw, opening an external window (assuming this window belongs to your application, not just a redirect to some unrelated external url) is not the way RIA is supposed to behave. And user may not expect that his browser windows are closed  without any user action - this kind of thing may even be scary to end user.